# How to properly declare an N-dimensional queue inline in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

If I have 2D queue of ints, I would expect to be able to declare it inline like so:

```
int my_queue[$][$] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

I have also seen

```
typedef int int_queue[$];
int_queue my_queue[$] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

Instead, when I compile, VCS provides me with an Incompatible Complex Type error:

```
  Type of source expression is incompatible with type of target expression. 
  Mismatching types cannot be used in assignments, initializations and 
  instantiations. The type of the target is 'int$[$][$]', while the type of 
  the source is 'bit[63:0]'.
```

Which implies to me that VCS expects the right hand side of the equation to be cast properly. The way around this that I have been using is:

```
typedef int int_queue[$];
typedef int_queue int_queue_of_queues[$];
int_queue_of_queues my_queue = int_queue_of_queues'{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

But this adds N extra typedefs and lines for N dimensions, and I would rather do this in one line. If I had a way to cast the right hand side of the declaration without a typedef, then this would be simple, but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array concatenation syntax only works on a single dimension.  You cannot nest the {}'s because of cases where there is ambiguity between array {} and integral {} concatenation. You need to use array assignment pattern in the outer, or both dimensions. I prefer using assignment patterns for both dimensions making it clearer that these are array elements, not integral concatenations.

```
int my_queue[$][$] = '{'{1, 2}, '{3, 4}};
```

See section 10.10 Unpacked array concatenation in the IEEE 1800-2017 
LRM.

Comment: Why does the concatenation syntax even exist? Assignment patterns would have been enough. It's not like the extra `'` needed for the assignment pattern is such a big distraction. Verilog legacy, perhaps?

Comment: @TudorTimi, SystemVerilog tried to do everything just using the concatenation syntax first. Then ambiguities arose in certain cases when trying to determine if each operand in the concatenation `{operand1,operand2,operand3}` was to be evaluated in a self-determined context (like in a Verilog Concatenation) or in the context of an assignment (like in an assignment pattern). That ambiguity is clearly evident when that operand is itself a concatenation expression. So the `'{}` was created to clearly indicate that each operand is in an assignment context.